# selecting date with regexp_extract

Tags: sql, impala

I will need to extract the year from a column name , , it is returning null value and the same number of character. i would want to only extract the date however there is a few column with the same number of character .

sample data in table

```
10020020
1172053041
597246141

3339110821
26590621
192133643
20190203
20180109
20170204
20190904
```

I have tried this,

```
select regexp_extract((colname), '([0-9]{8})', 1) from tablename
```

however it is returning the result that has the same number of characters with null values. i wish to only extract only the date which is 20170109,20190204 etc etc . what is the best approach and what did i go wrong ?

```
    10020020
    
    26590621
    20190203
    20180109
    20170204
    20190904
```

i have tried using wildcard `select regexp_extract((maxvalue), '([0-9]{8})', 1) like '%2019%' from profilingoverviewreport` but it returning boolean instead

Comment: your regexp_extract looks fine.. do you by change having spaces in your column?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match values which have exactly 8 digits, and those 8 digit values correspond to dates, then I suggest the following pattern:

```
^(20|19)[0-9]{6}$
```

Your updated SQL code:

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename
WHERE colname IREGEXP '^(20|19)[0-9]{6}$';
```

Check the demo to see the regex pattern correctly identifying the dates in your column:

### Demo

Comment: Hi Tim , Thank you for responding, i have tried your method . what i did  was " select distinct(regexp_extract(maxvalue, '^(20|19)[0-9]{6}$', 0)) from profilingoverviewreport " . however, it is returning null values as well. how can we only select the date but not the null or empty row using regex_extract method

Comment: @user12883347 Move the regex logic to the `WHERE` clause, and select record based only on that instead.

Comment: I creating this query on a BI tool e.g(Arcadia Data), therefor, they dont have where clause, Hence i have to try a different method to get this data out . so i have thought of regex . But Thank you Anw Tim

Comment: Well adding a `WHERE` clause is in fact the operation you seem to want here.